# Delphi Spring framework register generic type

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010, spring4d

Using the Delphi Spring framework, is it possible to register a generic type with the GlobalContainter? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
TMyBaseType = class
protected
  FName: string;
  function GetName: string; virtual;
  procedure SetName(Value: string); virtual;
public
  property Name: string read GetName write SetName;
end;

TMyFirstThing = class(TMyBaseType)
protected
  function GetName: string; override;
end;

TMySecondThing = class(TMyBaseType)
protected
  procedure SetName(Value: string); override;
end;

TMyGenericType<T: TMyBaseType> = class
public
  procedure DoSomethingWithIt(AObject: T);
  function GetTheSomethingsName(AObject: T): string;
end;

// I now want to be able to use the ServiceLocator to get me an instance
// such as TMyGenericType<TMyFirstThing> or TMyGenericType<TMySecondThing>
// but I cannot figure out how to register TMyGenericType<>

......

initialization
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TMyGenericType<>>;
// this line fails with the messages:
// [DCC Error] E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'RegisterType'
// [DCC Error] E2531 Method 'RegisterType' requires explicit type argument(s)
```

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible or if there's a better/alternative way to do it?
I'm using Delphi 2010 with the latest Spring4D framework. (I also have Delphi XE5 but the project itself is still 2010 due to 3rd party libraries).
Any ideas or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Will ask @StefanGlienke to jump in though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi does not have unbound (or open) generic types (something like `TMyGenericType<>`.

In your case you have to register every closed constructed generic type (`TMyGenericType<TMyFirstThing>`, `TMyGenericType<TMySecondThing>`, ...) individually.

More informations about the differences of generics in C#, C++ and Delphi:
http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/10/01/38465/

Comment: Would someone be able to create a base class for the generic and register that with Spring4D? It might help but I don't quite understand what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: He is trying to register an unbound generic type like you can with some DI containers in .NET. Since they work different there you can then instantiate the closed generic type at runtime (aka "specify in the T").

Comment: Neither Delphi nor .net have templates. I don't understand your first paragraph though.

Comment: @Stefan Not so. The implementation of Delphi generics is like, well generics. Specifically .net generics. Compilation errors are all found at the compilation of the generic class. The specialisation cannot lead to compilation errors in stark contrast to templates. If it was templates then we could use operators and we could do without constraints.

Comment: I suggest you have a read of this: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/10/01/38465/ If Delphi generics were implemented as templates, how could you instantiate a generic type without its source code?

Comment: Ha! Now I read your update where you also link to Craig's article and remove the text where you say Delphi generics are templates. Perhaps we should clear up the confusion in these comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and additional comments, registering the types individually seems to work great. I must now depart the conversation as you are way to intelligent for me and I will only embarrass myself if I say anything further :-)